# Task dependency in celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

[image: Task dependency]

Is such task dependency possible? 1 and 2 can be executed in parallel. 1a can be only executed when 1 is finished but 12b can be executed if both 1 and 2 are finished.

I know that I can make 1 and 2 a group, and then group(1, 2) | 12b can be a chain but how to make it so 1a starts just after 1 is finished, no matter what is going on with 2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Here is one way to do it. I used celery signal `task_success` to connect to a function which triggers a `celery task`

**my_tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery, task
from celery.signals import task_success

c = Celery('my_tasks')

@task
def t1():
    print('t1')

@task
def t2():
    print('t2')

@task
def t11():
    print('t11')

@task
def t12():
    print('t12')

def trigger_task(*args, **kwargs):
    t11.s().delay()

task_success.connect(trigger_task, sender=t1)
```

Testing the task:

```
In [6]: complex_task = chain(group(t1.s(), t2.s())(), t12.si().delay())
```

Here is the log.

```
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,082: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_tasks.t1[25dc70d2-263b-4e70-b9f2-56478bfedab5]
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,083: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_tasks.t2[0b0c5eb6-78fa-4900-a605-5bfd55c0d309]
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,084: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_tasks.t12[b08c616d-7a2d-4f7b-9298-2c8324b747ff]
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,084: WARNING/Worker-1] t1
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,084: WARNING/Worker-4] t2
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,085: WARNING/Worker-3] t12
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,086: INFO/MainProcess] Task my_tasks.t2[0b0c5eb6-78fa-4900-a605-5bfd55c0d309] succeeded in 0.00143978099914s: None
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,086: INFO/MainProcess] Task my_tasks.t1[25dc70d2-263b-4e70-b9f2-56478bfedab5] succeeded in 0.00191083699974s: None
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,087: INFO/MainProcess] Task my_tasks.t12[b08c616d-7a2d-4f7b-9298-2c8324b747ff] succeeded in 0.00184817300033s: None
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,087: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_tasks.t11[a3e3f0c6-ac1f-4888-893a-02eee3b29585]
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,088: WARNING/Worker-2] t11
[2014-10-10 12:31:05,089: INFO/MainProcess] Task my_tasks.t11[a3e3f0c6-ac1f-4888-893a-02eee3b29585] succeeded in 0.000978848000159s: None
```

I tried to connect directly to task but [it is throwing some error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284374/unable-to-connect-to-celery-task-from-a-celery-signal)