# Unable to connect to celery task from a celery signal?

Tags: python, celery, weak-references, djcelery

I am trying to connect `task2` from `task_success` signal

```
from celery.signals import task_success
from  celery  import  Celery

app  =  Celery()

@app.task
def task1():
    return 't1'

@app.task
def task2():
    return 't2'

task_success.connect(task2, sender=task1)
```

When I run this code, its throwing

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'PromiseProxy' object
```

If remove `app.task` decorator for task2, it works perfectly. But why is it unable to connect to celery task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technical details is that the task will be lazy evaluated by celery worker at first. That is, to create an object of **PromiseProxy** instead of **celery.app.task:Task** for performance

And by default, **signal.connect()** will attempt to use weak references to the receiver objects [Here, it is [**PromiseProxy**]. This is why you got such error.

The solution is quite simple, just change the **weak** parameter of **connect()** to **False**

```
task_success.connect(task2, sender=task1, weak=False)
```

But I found that it only works on windows.

The following one should be okay. To make sure that task decorator is applied last when using multiple decorators in combination with the task decorator

```
@app.task
@signals.task_success.connect(sender=task1)
def task2():
    return 't2'
```

Comment: This prevents the error but not invoking the task. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: I am not sure if it is because of the 'sender'. Just remove it and try

Comment: The celery internally use the pair of <id(sender), id(receiver)> to match the **sender** within 'signal.connect'. It seems that it does not work well.

Comment: Should make sure that the task decorator is applied last When using multiple decorators in combination with the task decorator. So we should connect first!

Comment: By the way, could you tell which platform you are using. I could get nothing when specifying `sender` on windows.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Celery 3.1.14.